# How do I programatically move the application window to current desktop?

Tags: plasma

In KDE it's really easy to setup window rules to be able to put application windows on specific desktop etc.

But how this can be done programmatically (not via keyboard shortcuts) but via scripting?

Particularly I'm interested to show the `ksysguard` application window (if it's running) on the current desktop after pressing a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

The [wmctrl](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/wmctrl/) tool can do this easily.

#### Prerequisites

Install wmctrl:

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

#### Use

"System Monitor" is the window name of `ksysguard` tool, so we will use it:

```
# Switch window's desktop to current and activate that window:
wmctrl -R "System Monitor"
```

To make this even more robust, we can use window's WM_CLASS (for `ksysguard` tool it's `ksysguard`):

```
# Switch window's desktop to current and activate that window:
wmctrl -x -R ksysguard
```